# Is the Wikipedia main article about topology correct?

Tags: general-topology, math-history

The Wikipedia entry 'Topology' describes topology as 'topology is concerned with the properties of a geometric object that are preserved under continuous deformations, such as stretching, twisting, crumpling and bending, but not tearing or gluing.'. But I'm not sure if that sentence correctly describes what topology is, I think it just describes a part of topology or some applications of topology. Nevertheless I think the Wikipedia article about topological space does better in explaining the generality of the concept, and also the main idea about topology (which is generalising the notion of space, in my opinion). Do you agree with me? Shall we change that Wikipedia entry and make it closer to the 'Topological space' one?

By the way, I'm sorry if this question turns out to be not appropriate for this forum.

Edit: I mean, isn't topology more than 'deformation of geometric objects'? Some topologies can be finite or just not related to the Euclidean spaces, how can we talk about 'deformation of geometric objects' in those topologies? or even about 'stretching, twisting, crumpling and bending'?

Comment: I don't really follow — which part of the description do you think is off? I can't really think of a way to rewrite "geometric object" that remains intelligible for laypeople.

Comment: What part of that description do you find inaccurate? Topology is the study of topological properties of topological spaces and these properties are those invariant under homeomorphisms---which are nothing but "continuous deformations" in more intuitive terms.

Comment: There is a separate article about "Topological space" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) which puts more emphasis on generality, so I don't think that a rewrite is needed.

Comment: It gives absolutely no sense of the things that interest me as a general and set-theoretic topologist, but I doubt that one can do much better for a capsule description that has any chance of making sense to a layman, and it has considerable historical justification. Besides, the article as a whole is reasonably good.

Comment: You can certainly come up with longer descriptions of topology that are more accurate than "deformation of geometric objects", but that short English description seems close to optimal as a widely understandable description of topology. So no, we should not change that Wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 2):

In the category $\mathsf{Top}$ of topological spaces the morphisms are precisely the continuous maps and the isomorphisms are homeomorphisms.

In other words, two homeomorphic spaces are, in the category $\mathsf{Top}$, up to isomorphism, considered to be indistinguishable.

Now homeomorphic spaces are in particular homotopy equivalent. And the notion of homotopy equivalence provides the intuitive picture of two spaces that are being continuously stretched and deformed into one another.

That's why we often talk about continuous deformations whenever the question arises what Topology in layman's terms actually is about.

Note that the Wikipedia article also refers to the Wikipedia articles about general topology, geometric topology, differential topology and algebraic topology.

In my opinion, the introduction on the main article about Topology on Wikipedia is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a good point. Though I would also like to note that some other Wikipedia entries, like the 'Abstract algebra' or 'Mathematical analysis', have more technical and straight-to-the-point introductions rather than the 'Topology' entry, which in my opinion has just a vague and too informal feeling to it.

Comment: I would also like to note that homeomorphism is more than homotopy, such that homotopy equivalent doesn't imply homeomorphic. And in some way it might be strange -at least to me- to think of homeomorphisms as the Wikipedia introduction describes it...